# Кто имеет доступ к персональной информации участниц и участников?

Tags: поддержка, модерация, инструменты-модератора

#### 1. Информация

В [**данном комментарии**](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/14595) модератор Stack Overflow на русском сообщил, что у участника сообщества имеется 3 почтовых адреса. Учитывая случай, когда другой модератор публично выложил [**сведения об участнике Stack Overflow на русском**](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/33115962#33115962), полученные [**из стороннего источника**](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/33115907#33115907), стало не очень комфортно.

Прочитал [**Privacy Policy**](http://stackexchange.com/legal/privacy-policy). Всюду употребляется местоимение «we». А кто имеется ввиду под «мы» — модераторы отдельных сообществ, их распорядители или кто-то ещё выше рангом — осталось непонятным.

#### 2. Вопросы

Какие категории пользовательниц/пользователей с высокими привилегиями имеют доступ к следующим видам информации?

1. количество e-mail адресов участниц/участников и сами адреса,
2. IP-адреса, (*Да, и IP пользовательниц/пользователей за какой срок — месяц, год, с момента регистрации, — хранятся в базах?*)
3. статистика посещений участницами/участниками страниц сайтов сети Stack Exchange.

Comment: У нас нет "участниц", только "участники".

Comment: Вообще-то, эти сведения вы вывалили как у нас в чате, так и вконтактике, самостоятельно, Nofate лишь пересказал их.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, данные о своих профилях в соцсетях я никогда и нигде не «вываливаю». Если не так, просьба предоставить ссылку. Та информация была получена не от меня лично. Спасибо.

Comment: "А кто имеется ввиду под «мы»" -- "StackExchange Inc."

Comment: @СашаЧерных не приведу, те сообщения в чате давно потерты. Но все о вашей ситуации лично я знаю с ваших же слов.

Comment: @D-side, если понимать так, то доступ имеется только у сотрудников, а не модераторов. Спасибо.

Comment: @СашаЧерных отвечает за это всё равно компания, модераторы принимают отдельное соглашение при вступлении на пост. Это может быть оговорено там.

Comment: @D-side, ясно, спасибо.

Comment: Я помню как тогда обсуждение с тобой затёрли в чате. Причём я половину читал, а половину уже не видел, т. к. затёрли.

Comment: "Мы" - значит компания. Компания состоит из личностей, связанных юридическими бумагами и законами, работающих на связующих их людей. Модераторы - добровольцы-волонтёры, принимающих присягу без юридической ответственности, которым выдают не приватную в общем смысле, но деликатную информацию, так что ответ очевиден.

Comment: > модератор публично выложил сведения об участнике Stack Overflow на русском Дело в том, что данный участник сам постоянно публикует сведения о своей личной жизни, в том числе вплетая их в каждый вопрос и ответ: в имена файлов и функций в коде, в строки, в скриншоты, в картинки-примеры. Лично я не хотел бы знать никаких личных сведений об этом участнике. Но, к моему глубокому сожалению, знаю, причём мне постоянно напоминают. В примере выше модератор просто перефразировал ту информацию, которую вышеуказанный участник опубликовал самостоятельно. Раскрытия *персональной информации* не было.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

К служебной информации вроде ip и email имеют доступ модераторы и сотрудники компании.

[Доступ к аналитике сайта](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/site-analytics), открывается после 25000 репутации, но в ней нет информации по конкретным участникам.

> статистика посещений участницами/участниками страниц сайтов сети Stack Exchange.

У сотрудников компании есть прямой доступ к базе данных, поэтому отследить действия конкретного участника вполне возможно.

Comment: Grundy, верно ли понял, что доступа к информации третьего типа нет вообще ни у кого? Спасибо.

Comment: @СашаЧерных, что за информация третьего типа? Обновил ответ.

Comment: @Grundy, *3. статистика посещений участницами/участниками страниц сайтов сети Stack Exchange.*